# Getting Data from SQL and putting in a list

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am getting data from SQL and putting it in list. here's what I am trying now,

```
public class Fruit //custom list
{
     public string aID { get;set; }  // can be more then 1
     public string bID { get;set; }  // only 2 but different aID
     public string name { get;set; } // only 1 for selection of aID and bID
}
```

and this is how i am getting data from sql,

```
var Fruitee = new Fruit();

using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(CS()))
{
      cn.Open();
      SqlCommand sqlCommand= new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable", cn);
      SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
      while (reader.Read())
      {
             Fruitee.add(reader["aID"], reader["bID"],reader["name"]) // ??? not sure what to put here  as add is not available
      }
      cn.Close();
}
```

Table looks like this,

aID,  bID, name

**

- Problem

**

I am stuck how to add items to list and **also is it best practice ?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Fruit f = new Fruit();
    f.aID = (string) reader["aID"];
    f.bID = (string) reader["bID"];
    f.name = (string) reader["name"];
    fruits.Add(f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = new List<Fruit>();

  while (reader.Read())
  {
         list.Add(new Fruit() { aID = reader["aID"].ToString(), bID = reader["bID"].ToString(), name = reader["name"].ToString() });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Fruitee = new List<Fruit>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Fruitee.Add(new Fruit() { aID = reader["aID"].ToString(), bID = reader["bID"].ToString(), name = reader["name"].ToString() });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually **read** from the reader and that's what you're not doing.  However, be aware of DBNulls.

So assuming that your custom list has an **add** function you could do something like the following.

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    Fruitee.add(reader["aID"], reader["bID"], reader["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Can't use Fruitee.add as it is not a list.

Comment: Which is why I made the statement if the custom list has an add function.

Comment: Yes but fruitee variable is a class which stores these parameters. Even if it has an add function, where will it store it? It needs to have a list inside that class to store those parameters.