# Use DataTable.Load() without creating all column properties

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

**I'm loading data from a SQL server database like this:**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from x", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(rd, LoadOption.PreserveChanges);
```

**Issue:**

The `Load()` function initializes the table columns with `ColumnName` and `DataType`, but it also looks deeper into the database, and it adds some constraints like `AllowDBNull`, `AutoIncrement`, `MaxLength`, etc.

However, this leads to problems in my application, because I want to further process the data internally.

So, is it possible to do a `Load()` just with setting the most basic properties (which come directly from the `select` statement), without setting `AllowDBNull`, `MaxLength`, and so on? Or do I need to clean these values after the `Load()` ? Or is there another alternative to calling `Load()` ?

Comment: Load the data in a `List<T>` instead of `DataTable`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856687/getting-data-from-sql-and-putting-in-a-list

Comment: @Habib That's also a good idea !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want that behaviour don't use [`DataTable.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsze9wte(v=vs.110).aspx) but [`DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from x", conn))
    da.Fill(dt);
```

> The `Fill` operation then adds the rows to destination `DataTable` objects
>   in the `DataSet`, creating the `DataTable` objects if they do not already
>   exist. When creating `DataTable` objects, **the `Fill` operation normally
>   creates only column name metadata**. However, if the `MissingSchemaAction`
>   property is set to `AddWithKey`, appropriate primary keys and
>   constraints are also created.

I have tested it, it just loads the column-names and types, all other properties like `AllowDbNull` or `MaxLength` have their default values which might be right or wrong.

Comment: Oh that's interesting .... I had thought that the DataAdapter does even "more" ... but it's not true ... indeed, it works ... `MaxLength` is -1, and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Well, yes, I only had found some problems recently, and that's why I'm abstaining from the DataAdapter. It is "too intelligent", because if you use it for a view (instead of a table), then it will create delete/update/insert  commands for the underlying tables, instead of for the view. Which is bad, if you are using a security setup which allows only access to the view, and not to the tables. But that's another story.