# How get SQL Server table to be store a list?

Tags: c#, .net, datareader

As a java developer, this is possible easily. But I wasn't able to achieve it in C#. I want to get data from the SQL Server database and store them in a list that is of type object to meet the table needs.

The object:

```
class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the table in the database:

[image]

and the code:

```
public List<Category> GetCategoryList() 
{
        connect.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Category", connect);

        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        connect.Close();
}
```

I believe there is something named `DataReader` I got to use it but I couldn't find an explanation or an example of how to use it in such a situation like mine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Data from SQL and putting in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856687/getting-data-from-sql-and-putting-in-a-list)

Comment: Read up on Dapper. Short answer - use Dapper (or another lightweight ORM) rather than ADO.NET. _It will be similar to using Hibernate, but a fair bit simpler._

Comment: You could also just fill a datatable and cut down on the overhead of converting to a `List<T>`

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp DataTables have considerable overhead of their own.

Comment: How did you go with Dapper @AbdallahRizk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Category> GetCategoryList() 
{
    List<Category> columnData = new List<Category>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From Category", connect);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                columnData.Add(new Category {
                    Id= reader["Id"] is DBNull ? null : int.Parse(reader["Id"]),
                    Name = reader["Name"] is DBNull ? null : reader["Name"].ToString() 
                });
            }         
        }
    }
    return columnData;
}
```

Comment: The connection should also have its using block, or execute the reader with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`

Comment: `Category(reader)` You've moved the hard bit of the problem to the constructor, and not showed that code to the OP.

Comment: Also, the `cmd` object should be disposed

Comment: `Id` is not nullable. Also, I suspect `int.Parse` is not needed if it is _already_ an `int`.